# How to redim Arrays in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have repetitive snippets of code that increases the size of dynamic arrays when needed so prefer them in a subroutine. I have been googling for half a day and cannot seem to find a solution to redim an array in another routine. Found a solution but that was for an early 2000s version of VBA and doesn't work with this Excel 2013 version.

`reDim` only `reDim` the size of theArray but not the actual `arrGrp` which should have been passed by reference. I am using Excel 2013. Any solution on how to `reDim` an array passed `byRef`?

```
Sub ArraySizeUp(ByRef theArray) 'theArray() doesn't work also

    'increment size by 1
    If ArrayIsAllocated(theArray) Then
        ReDim Preserve theArray(UBound(theArray) + 1)
    Else
        ReDim theArray(0)
    End If

End Sub
```

-

```
Sub Main()

    Dim arrGrp()

    ArraySizeUp arrGrp
    'Call ArraySizeUp(arrGrp) - doesnt work as well

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is happening for you with Excel 2013? The code looks fine to me, though you haven't shown the code for `IsArrayAllocated`. Arrays are only passed `ByRef` by the way.

Comment: FWIW `ReDim Preserve theArray(UBound(theArray) + 1)` is rather inefficient. Make the resizing worthwhile, not just +1. Better: don't use an array unless you know how many elements you're going to need.

Comment: Exactly what does "doesn't work" mean? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, if the `ArrayIsAllocated` function is coded properly. I don't see it in you your question, so I cannot tell. But consider this code:

```
Sub ArraySizeUp(ByRef theArray)
    ReDim theArray(0)
    theArray(0) = 5
    ReDim Preserve theArray(UBound(theArray) + 1)
    theArray(1) = 6
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim arrGrp()
    ArraySizeUp arrGrp
End Sub
```

I just removed the `ArrayIsAllocated` function, but the code otherwise is identical to yours, and it runs well. The first `ReDim` adds one items and I assigned it 5, then the second `ReDim` adds another item and I assigned it 6. When you get back to `Main()`, you will have the `arrGrp` with two items, 5 and 6.

So you need to check the code in the `ArrayIsAllocated` function and fix it. If you need help, post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise. The code works now. I do not know why the problem occurred. I spent 2 hours last night debugging the problem to no avail. Extensive googling and reading stackoverflow found nothing that helped so posted a question here as a last resort.

The problem specifically is when I "watched" arrGrp and theArray, only theArray has its size incremented and not arrGrp. It in fact worked the first time. Second time onwards, the problem started and I thought it was because I used "ArraySizeUp arrGrp" instead of "Call ArraySizeUp(arrGrp)", even though my reading of stackoverflow indicate "call" is not necessary. From then on, it completely refused to increment the size of arrGrp. This throws an error later on when accessing UBound(arrGrp).

The only thing I did not do was shutdown and start up the computer during that period. I can only surmise that somehow resolved the problem. Thank you all for your kind contributions. I have extensive experience in Adobe Director's lingo programming but only picked up VBA yesterday for this adhoc task so the VBA programming perspective is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot redim an array defined with dim. You need to start with redim

```
 Sub Main()

  ReDim arrGrp(0)

 ArraySizeUp arrGrp

 Debug.Print UBound(arrGrp)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Of course you can `ReDim` an array defined with `Dim`, have you tried it? Try the code in my answer, it runs and gives the expected result.

Comment: That's not true - you can `Redim` as long as the array wasn't declared with specific bounds originally.