# VBA - filling an array with values from many separate cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, cell

I need a simple solution for inputing numbers from the cells specified in one cell into an array.

E.g. A1 is filled with particular text: `A3`, `B4`, `D10`, `F1:F45`

I need values from these cells in the array in VBA - how can I do this withput specifing everything in code? I've tried something like:

```
Dim x() As Array
x = Range(Range("A1").Value).Value
```

However it doesn't work apparently :)

Answer (score 0):

You want the `Array()` to capture multiple values, e.g.:

```
Sub generateArray()
    Dim testArray As Variant
    testArray = Array(Cells(1, 1).Value, Cells(2, 2).Value)
    Debug.Print testArray(0)
    Debug.Print testArray(1)
End Sub
```

Regarding the use of adding multiple arrays to your array, you will want to create a composite array dimensioned to your two previous `ubound()`, or simply `redim` parameters and keep adding to the new array.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817848/how-to-redim-arrays-in-vba) for more information on the latter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `A3`, `B4`, `D10`, `F1:F45` are non-contiguous, and presumably you want a 1D array, you can use a loop:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("A1").Value)
    
Dim arr As Variant
ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)
    
Dim counter As Long
counter = 1
    
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    arr(counter) = cell.Value
    counter = counter + 1
Next
```