# Iterate through arrays and put them into one array

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to create a function that returns an array of an unspecified number of elements. The number of elements depends on the number of elements passed through my function.

```vb
Public Function dekonstruer_update_statement(oppdateringsfelter As Variant, oppdateringsverdier As Variant, oppdateringsteller As Long, oppdateringstabell As String, oppdateringskriteriefelter As Variant, oppdateringskriterier As Variant, oppdateringskriterieteller As Long) As Variant
```

All the "Variants" in the function are supposed to be an array of x elements like so

```
(Array(value1, value2, value3...etc.))
```

I want to iterate through the "Arrays" and put them into one Array.

```vb
Dim dekonstruerArray() As Variant
Dim i, j, k, l, m As Long

i = 0

For j = 0 To oppdateringsteller - 1
    dekonstruerArray(i) = oppdateringsfelter(j)
    i = i + 1
Next j

For k = 0 To oppdateringsteller - 1
    dekonstruerArray(i) = oppdateringsfelter(k)
    i = i + 1
Next k

dekonstruerArray(i) = oppdateringstabell
i = i + 1

For l = 0 To oppdateringskriterieteller - 1
    dekonstruerArray(i) = oppdateringskriteriefelter(l)
    i = i + 1
Next l

For m = 0 To oppdateringskriterieteller - 1
    dekonstruerArray(i) = oppdateringskriterier(m)
    i = i + 1
Next m

dekonstruer_update_statement = dekonstruerArray
```

I get

> Subscript out of range (Error 9)

since I cannot access the (i) position within my array.

I tried to assign the variant `dekonstruerArray()` to `dekonstruerArray(0 to x)` where `x` is a variable calculated by counting all the values inside the "Arrays" passed to the function. This number will vary throughout my program.

I get

> compile error: Constant expression required

I could go for a collection instead but I want to understand how arrays work.

Comment: Explore ReDim statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redim Arrays in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817848/how-to-redim-arrays-in-vba)

Comment: Try this `ReDim dekonstruerArray(oppdateringskriterieteller)`

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comments `REDIM` is the answer.

Assuming lower-bound of arrays is zero (i.e. data not started from index 1):

```
FUNCTION Concat(X AS VARIANT, Y AS VARIANT, Z AS VARIANT) AS VARIANT
    CONST K = 2
    ' K= number of arrays-1
    DIM A AS VARIANT
    REDIM A(UBOUND(X) + UBOUND(Y) + UBOUND(Z)+ K)

    DIM i,j AS INTEGER

    j = 0
    FOR i= 0 TO UBOUND(X)
        A(j)= X(i)
        j= j + 1
    NEXT

    FOR i= 0 TO UBOUND(Y)
        A(j)= Y(i)
        j= j + 1
    NEXT

    FOR I = 0 TO UBOUND(Z)
        A(j)= Z(i)
        j= j + 1
    NEXT

    Concat= A
END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tips about using arrays in VBA.

1. If you are iterating over a whole array then use `For myIndex = Lbound(myArray) to Ubound(myArray)` as this allows you to use an array without knowing what its start and end indexes are.
2. If your array came from an Excel range then it will always be a 2 dimensional array (even if you just want a row or column).
3. Try working with arrays as a single entity rather than item by item.

One of the big issues of your code is the need to create an array of the correct size, which is why other comments have directed you to redim.  However, redim can be an expensive operation so it is better to write code that can avoid ReDim if you can.

The code below shows how to use a Scripting.Dictionary to achieve your goal.  Two versions. One is a 'straight' translation of your code.  The second version shows how to write in a more flexible manner as the arrays to be consolidated no longer need to be specified in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function dekonstruer_update_statement _
( _
    oppdateringsfelter As Variant, _
    oppdateringsverdier As Variant, _
    oppdateringsteller As Long, _
    oppdateringstabell As String, _
    oppdateringskriteriefelter As Variant, _
    oppdateringskriterier As Variant, _
    oppdateringskriterieteller As Long _
) As Variant

    Dim myD As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myD = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim myItem As Variant
    With myD
        ' using only those parameters declared as Variant
        ' Using the .count method of the scripting.dictionary to provide the needed Key
        For Each myItem In oppdateringsfelter
            myD.Add .Count, myItem
        Next
        
        For Each myItem In oppdateringsverdier
            myD.Add .Count, myItem
        Next
           
        For Each myItem In oppdateringskriteriefelter
            .Add .Count, myItem
        Next
    
        For Each myItem In oppdateringskriterier
            .Add .Count, myItem
        Next
    End With
    
    ' Return the combined arrays by using the .Items method of  the scripting.dictionary
    dekonstruer_update_statement = myD.Items
    
End Function

' Which of course would be more flexible when written as

'in your code
dekonstruer_update_statement oppdateringsfelter, oppdateringsverdier, oppdateringskriteriefelter, oppdateringskriterier

Public Function dekonstruer_update_statement(ParamArray ipParamArray() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim myD As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myD = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    For Each myArray In ipParamArray
        If Not VBA.IsArray(myArray) Then
            Err.Raise 17 ' expand this line to the error you wish to return
            Exit Function
        End If
        ConsolidateArray myArray
    Next
    
    dekonstruer_update_statement = myD.Items
        
End Function

Public Sub ConsolidateArray(ByRef iopD As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef ipArray As Variant)
    
    Dim myItem As Variant
    For Each myItem In ipArray
        iopD.Add iopD.Count, myItem
    Next
    
End Sub
```

And just for fun, if I were using my own Library of VBA structures and functions the above would be achieved as follows in a single line of VBA code.

```
Set dekonstruer_update_statement = SeqA.Deb _
    .AddRange(oppdateringsfelter) _
    .AddRange(oppdateringsverdier) _
    .AddRange(oppdateringskriteriefelter) _
    .AddRange(oppdateringskriterier)
```